# Creating a typetuple from a variadic template argument list in D

Tags: templates, d, template-mixins

I have a templated struct of the following form:

```
struct Command(T) {
    alias T CommandType;
    // ...
}
```

In addition, I have another container struct that holds a bunch of these `Command` structs:

```
struct CommandList(Command...) {
}
```

What I'd like to do is, via templates and/or mixins, create a TypeTuple alias in `CommandList` which contains the `CommandType`s, in order, of each of the template `Command` arguments. For example, I'd like for something like this to happen:

```
struct CommandList(Command!int, Command!long, Command!string, Command!float) {
    alias TypeTuple!(int, long, string, float) CommandListType; // This would be dynamically generated by templates/mixins...
}
```

Would this be possible to do, and if so, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
import std.typetuple;

struct Command(T) { alias T CommandType; }
template getCommandType(T) { alias T.CommandType getCommandType; }

struct CommandList(Command...) {
    alias staticMap!(getCommandType, Command) CommandListType;
}

pragma(msg, CommandList!(Command!int, Command!long).CommandListType);
```